# Converting string to a simple type

Tags: c#, .net, types, type-conversion

.Net framework contains a great class named Convert that allows conversion between simple types, DateTime type and String type. Also the class support conversion of the types implementing IConvertible interface.

The class has been implemented in the very first version of .Net framework. There were a few things in the first .Net framework that were not done quite right. For example .Parse methods on simple types would throw an exception if the string couldn't be parsed and there would be no way to check if exception is going to be thrown in advance.

A future version of .Net Framework removed this deficiency by introducing the TryParse method that resolved this problem.

The Convert class dates back to time of the old Parse method, so the ChangeType method on this class in implemented old style - if conversion can't be performed an exception is thrown.

Take a look at the following code:

```
public static T ConvertString<T>(string s, T @default)
{
    try
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return @default;
    }            
}
```

This code basically does what I want. However I would pretty much like to avoid the ugly try/catch here. I'm sure, that similar to TryParse, there is a modern method of rewriting this code without the catch-all. Could you suggest one?

Comment: There's no shame in using a try/catch if it's only going to happen rarely eg if something's in the wrong format. It's if you're hitting the catch most of the time you've got performance issues.

Comment: Yep, that would be another reason why I'd like to avoid it. Sometimes it's hard to predict how and where your code is going to be used / called from, so you'd want to do it "right".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method, and there never will be.

`Convert.Change` calls the `IConvertible` implementation of the object that you pass it to perform the conversion.

Since the `IConvertible` interface does not define `TryConvertTo` methods, it is not possible to write a `TryConvertTo` method.  (Adding new methods to `IConvertible` would be a *major* breaking change)

It would be possible for Microsoft to create a `ISafeConvertible` interface with additional methods, but I don't think they will.

Comment: I mean method not as in "method on a type" but method as a way of achieving something. Thank you for your answer, though. To expand, I was expecting a newer different version of Convert class that might not be bound to IConvertible as such. Or something to this extent.

Comment: All you can do is write your own `switch` statement.